# netsh fails to set MTU

Tags: windows-10, networking, netsh

I'm trying to set the MTU for a Mellanox 100Gb NIC using `netsh`.  The command works for small MTU values, but it fails for anything larger than 2000.  The card is a ConnectX-6 and I know it supports jumbo frames.  What's wrong with `netsh` here?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface 17 store=persistent mtu=1900
Ok.

PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface 17 store=persistent mtu=2000
The parameter is incorrect.

PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces

Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          75  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 16           5        9000  disconnected  Mellanox100
 14          15        1500  connected     Slot03 Port 1
 12           5        1500  disconnected  Slot03 Port 2
 17           5        1950  connected     MellanoxStatic
```

The other weird thing is that the device properties in Device Manager are totally disconnected from what I see in `netsh`.  Changing values in one place does not cause them to change in the other (both directions).  I'm running Windows 10 (20H2) with the latest driver 2.80.25134.0 and the latest firmware 22.32.2004.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see a `MellanoxStatic` device with an MTU of 1950. Try to see if 1950 is the real limit.

Comment: According to the manual this card supports up to 9600